# Can we hide the yellow button bar for readonly user when he opened an Excel?

Tags: office-integration, read-only

We are using SP2013 on-premise standard edition.

When user with readonly permission opened a workbook link (e.g. http://sharepoint.com/sites/abc/shared document/abc.xlsx) he will see the yellow bar as below:

[image]

When he click on "Edit Document" it will prompt for error

> A problem occured while connecting to the server. If the problem
>   continues, contact your administrator.

Is there any workaround to hide the yellow bar?

P.S. If user click "..." > "Open", the document will be opened in read-only mode WITHOUT the yellow bar. But how can I make the behavior as default?